# getting error while creating react.js app using npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs

Getting error while creating react.js app using `npx create-react-app my-app`

```
yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @testing-library/react > @types/testing-library__react > @types/testing-library__dom@7.5.0: This is a stub types definition. testing-library__dom provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=5".
error An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\\ecommerce-app\\my-app\\node_modules\\@babel\\compat-data\\node_modules\\.bin'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "E:\\ecommerce-app\\my-app\\yarn-error.log". 
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
`yarnpkg add @testing-library/react@^9.3.2 @testing-library/jest-dom@^4.2.4 @testing-library/user-event@^7.1.2` failed
```

**Yarn log file**

```
Arguments: 
  E:\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js add @testing-library/react@^9.3.2 @testing-library/jest-dom@^4.2.4 @testing-library/user-event@^7.1.2
```

PATH:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\bin;E:\Pritesh\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;E:\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\Miniconda3;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Pritesh Choksi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
```

Yarn version:
`1.22.4`

Node version:
`10.16.0`

Platform:
`win32 x64`

Trace:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\ecommerce-app\my-app\node_modules\@babel\compat-data\node_modules\.bin'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have to write permission to create a project with this directory. Open your terminal with admin privileges then run create command.

Comment: Did you check the "yarn-error.log" file for detailed information? And can you share log file content?

Comment: Trace: 
  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\ecommerce-app\my-app\node_modules\@babel\compat-data\node_modules\.bin'                                                  
Is this much fine as the entire log is too long to add in comment

Comment: I have added the log file above in the query itself...Do have a look

Comment: Maybe the problem is npx itself, I'm not sure. But You have yarn. Why are you using npx? You can create a react app with `yarn create react-app app-name`.